# Excel limited rows issue

Tags: excel, data-analysis

I am working on a bank loan analysis project and I am facing an issue with the number of rows in my "Previous_application.csv" file. It contains 1.6 million  rows, which exceeds the limit of Excel (1 million rows). How can I manage this situation since I need to perform the analysis using Excel?

Comment: Split into two and analyse each separately, then combine results. But it depends on what you are looking for.

Comment: Please use universal measurements instead of local words like *lakh*

Comment: Use power query. There is no row limit. You can analyze your data in power query, or use it to split your data, or create a pivot table directly from power query.